# Azure DataFactory & @{linkedService.MyVariable} substitution as override params on a release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I am new to Azure Data Factory, but I've read all the documentation and I'm still unsure on how to put this together.

My Azure Data Factory contains 2 linked services:

- one for a blob storage
- one for an Azure SQL DB.

Both of these services are set up with linked service connections and use System Assigned Managed Identity.

What I need is to be able to switch the environment when a release pipeline is run and configure the linked services to use the values matching the environment (ex: use the Dev/QA/UAT blob storage location endpoint as an example)

I see the param come in when accessing the override values on the ARM Template Deployment task, but I'm unsure how this is supposed to work.

In my case, the override values looks like this:
-factoryName "my-adf-dev"
-My_Project_Import_properties_typeProperties_serviceEndpoint "@{linkedService().storageEndpoint}"

How to be sure that the value of @{linkedService().storageEndpoint} is correctly set and the Data Factory will run correctly for the targeted environment ?

Do I create a release variable and attempt to substitute the linked service portion, do I have to create a release variable for the entire string, or ?

Thanks in advance.

Update #1: I'm using Azure ADO Release Pipeline with an ARM Template Deployment Task. Obfuscated template parameters look as such:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "factoryName": {
            "value": "my-adf-dev"
        },
        "My_Project_Database_connectionString": {
            "value": "Integrated Security=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;Data Source=@{linkedService().databaseServer};Initial Catalog=@{linkedService().databaseName}"
        },
        "My_Project_Import_properties_typeProperties_serviceEndpoint": {
            "value": "@{linkedService().storageEndpoint}"
        },
        "trg_ehs_process_import_properties_typeProperties_scope": {
            "value": "/subscriptions/XXX/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/myStorageAccountEnv"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide obfuscated elements of your ARM template, and the parameters ? I have to work on a similar case with Synapse (which is quite similar on some aspects to ADF). I made value replacement in the pipeline. The component depends on your devops tool.

Comment: What is your dev ops tool ?

Comment: @RomEh Updated with requested info. Thx

Comment: @TonyStark i managed to get this working using https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens and the pipeline library, i just cant get it to work for global parameters

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that is looking for a possible answer, perhaps this will shed some light.

I never found a way to pass the @{linkedService().storageEndpoint} directly from the release pipeline. Apparently they get passed down through a chain of variables. The first of which is a global variable @pipeline().myvariable, then a @dataaset().myvariable, and finally your @linkedservice variable.

The second thing I did was to switch everything over to read from key vault instead of managed identity, but that's an unrelated item.